# VSTS - Continuous Delivery - Release Trigger not working with tags

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

## UPDATE 2017/02/28

The tags in the release triggers are not source control tags, they are tags that can be generated by your build step. You can tag your builds automatically (see below), or manually during a build, I haven't tried this yet.

[image]

My assumption about the tags were **flawed**, which makes this question pretty much invalid. However I am going to try and see if I can find some sort of workaround for my exact scenario, and then I will post it here.

## Background

I am setting up our CI/CD pipeline using VSTS, and part of our branching strategy is that only `release/*` branches that are **tagged** will be deployed to production.

### Problem

I am trying to trigger a release using the VSTS Continuous Deployment feature, which should be able to work with branches and tags. At first I tried this, thinking that I could use a wildcard for everything:

#### Attempt 1

[image]

The trigger never worked, so I decided that it is probably not supported (because I can't find any documentation around it). So I tried an explicit tag.

#### Attempt 2

[image]

That didn't work either, so I decided to abandon the `release/*` wildcard altogether and just attempt it with a specific release branch.

#### Attempt 3

[image]

Still didn't work. I am either missing some really important steps here, or it is broken. Please help.

**PS** - *For every attempt, I made sure that I committed a new file in git, tagged the commit, and kicked off a new CI build.*

**PS** - *Specifying a wildcard for branches like* `release/*` *works perfectly, as long as you leave the tag field empty*

Comment: Can you send out a mail to RM_Customer_Queries@microsoft.com with VSTS account details, Release Definition Name/Id, Build definition Name/Id ? 

The support team should be able to help you debug the issue.

Comment: One more question, how are you tagging your builds ?? The tags should be attached to the build before the build completes i.e.  either using a task or manually when build is in progress.

Comment: @HarshilLodhi I am confused by your last comment. Are the tags not git tags for your feature branch? What task will then tag it, if it is not git tags?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is filtered by the build tag instead of source tag/label.

[image]

For example, a release definition CD with myTag filter, then the corresponding new build need to have myTag.

To add the tag to build, you can refer to these steps:

1. Edit your build definition
2. Add PowerShell step (Inline Script: Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]myTag")

Comment: Thank you @starian-MSFT, but we moved one step back, and now we're kicking off CI builds from PowerShell based on the git tagging process I mentioned. So the build tags are no longer a requirement, because we can now just deploy on successful build because the CI is kicked off conditionally. But the inline PowerShell step is invaluable!

Comment: I would expect a build tag to be created automatically based on any source tags. It would also be very nice to be able to use wildcards for tags in the release triggers.

Comment: @starain-MSFT I followed your advice here and set up a powershell step that correctly set my build tags based on branch name but the condition I have to kick off for that tag **still** never fires. Any thoughts?

Comment: @starain-MSFT This is the issue I'm seeing for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149289/ci-cd-deployment-conditions-not-triggering I'll gladly upvote and accept if you are able to help me out

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the inline-script option, since there are several powershell options to pick from, inline was much easier.  I found the microsoft documentation for the [vsts-tasks commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) also