# TFS Build tagging

Tags: powershell, tfs, build

I am using TFS for source and build of my project. After successful build I want to automate the tagging of build using powershell or any TFS task. And after that I wanted to use the same tag to deploy in specific environment. Can you guide me how can use this?

Comment: What things have you tried that didn't work? What version of TFS are you using? Are you using the XAML build system or the newer build system?

Comment: Hard to say unless you give more detail, I had a similar problem and was able to resolve my issue with a combination of TFS build tasks using custom conditions and Powershell++ task inline commands available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

Comment: similar question that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501293/vsts-continuous-delivery-release-trigger-not-working-with-tags

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using VNext build, you can use the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#add-a-tag-to-a-build) to add tags during the build, then set a CD release to deploy the tagged artifacts.

**PowerShell sample:**

```
$buildid= $env:BUILD_BUILDID
$TagName= $env:BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME + $env:BUILD_BUILDID
$Uri = "http://mo-12r2:8080/tfs/CollectionLC/0418Scrum/_apis/build/builds/$buildid/tags/$($TagName)?&api-version=2.0"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri 

Write-Host "BuildID:" $buildid
Write-Host "TagName:" $TagName
```

You can follow below steps to do that:

1. Create a PowerShell script and check in to server, See above sample
2. Create a build definition and add a PowerShell task as the end task
3. Select the PowerShell script to run
4. Create a Release definition with **Continuous Deployment** enabled
   and link the build definition created in step2 as the artifacts. (You can also select any tagged build to deploy if you set manual release.)

[image]

Comment: @sunil bindra Have you resolved your issue by above workaround?