# CI/CD Deployment Conditions Not Triggering

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've been fighting with this for over a day now. I have a simple requirement inside of a VSTS CI/CD pipeline that I'm trying to build that any branch following the pattern `release/*` or `hotfix/*` should trigger a deployment to my QA environment. Here is my branch based configuration:

[image]

This configuration does not trigger the deployment as expected. As you can see in the screenshot below the release ran but did not trigger against any of my environments. (QA is the second grey square from the right and should be green or red depending on whether the deployment succeeded or failed).

[image]

In an attempt to work around this, I tried using Build Tags instead. I added a Powershell step that conditionally adds Build Tags based on the name of the branch.

```
$branchName = $Env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH

if ($branchName -like '*release/*')
{
    Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]release"
}

if ($branchName -like '*hotfix/*')
{
    Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]hotfix"
}
```

This correctly sets the Build Tags as I can see right on the build artifact and in logs that the tag was applied. However, modifying my Deployment Conditions to be Tag aware results in exactly the same behavior as my attempt using branches:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**
As requested, here is the CI definition with the Get Sources step shown. There is no option to add multiple branch conditions here. They are set in the Triggers section.

[image: Get Sources CI Config]
[image: CI Triggers]

Comment: Have you tried it with a single branch instead of a wildcard pattern?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, the only time it ever triggers is if I specify a specific branch name. As a temporary workaround I can manually add in known release/hotfix branches but VSTS is supposed to support more intelligent deployment conditions. All through the UI they let you do pattern matching

Comment: Can you also share the settings of the Release Artifacts? Is it a build? If yes, also share the settings of "Get Source" step in build definition.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I have updated the question with additional screenshots to show these configs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by two different conditions are configured in the same time since VSTS use "AND" operator rather than "OR" operator here. In this scenario, the deployment condition would like this: `"Artifact Branch from Release/*" AND "Artifact Branch from Feature/*"` which cannot be met. If you double click on the "Release 28" to open it and move your mouse on the "i" icon, you should see the reason why it is not triggered. Please check if it is the reason I mentioned above.

[image]

The workaround is create a new deployment environment and clone the settings from QA and then separate the two conditions in the two environments.

Comment: THANK YOU! I can't believe it was something so simple in the end. The UI could definitely be more clear in how the conditions are applied to help avoid this confusion.